# Chatter window is not displaying for user

Tags: chatter, chatter-groups, chatter-answers

Good morning to all of u guys,

Here As a admin i am able to see chatter window But my users are not able to see the chatter window.

i was enable the chatter option from the below path

setup->app setup->customize->chatter->settings

As a admin i am able to see that window but my users are facing such kind of problem.

is there any other option from the user if i am missing to check or uncheck?

Thanks in advance for your urgent support

Comment: Hello can any one update on this?

Comment: please share your comment on this